# Jquery jqx validation not works properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, webforms

I use **jqx** - jquery plugins and widgets - for simple form validation in ruby-on-rails application.

Simplest html form example:

```
<form id="newForm">
   <input type="text" id="name"/>        
</form>
```

Now, let's consider the same simple javascript snippet, which performs validation:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{      
  //Form input element as jqx input
  $("#name").jqxInput({ placeHolder: "Enter name"});

  //Form validation
  $("#newForm").jqxValidator(
  {
     hintType: 'label',         
     rules: [
              { 
               input: "#name", 
               message: "Name is required!", 
               action: "keyup, blur", 
               rule: "required"
              }
            ],
      onError: function () { alert('You havent filled the form correctly!'); }//this handler not works
  });
});
```

In general, validation works fine, except **onError** property - this handler does not react on **keyup** and **blur** events (alert window not appears).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{      
  //Form input element as jqx input
  $("#name").jqxInput({ placeHolder: "Enter name"});

  //Form validation
  $("#newForm").jqxValidator(
  {
     hintType: 'label',         
     rules: [
              { 
               input: "#name", 
               message: "Name is required!", 
               action: "keyup, blur", 
               rule: "required"
              }
            ],
      onError: function () { alert('You havent filled the form correctly!'); }
  });

  //Fire validation implicitly
  $("#name").bind("blur keyup", function()
  { 
    $('#newForm').jqxValidator('validate'); 
  });

});
```